# SSRS TotalPages vs OveralTotalPages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am looking at the built-in global variables `Globals!TotalPages` and `Globals!OverallTotalPages`.  The following are the descriptions in Report Builder:

**TotalPages:**

> The total number of pages in the current continous page sequence. The
>   number can be reset by using page breaks. Can be used only in a page
>   header and footer.

**OveralTotalPages:**

> The total number of pages in the report. Can be used only in a page
>   header and footer.

---

I don't understand the difference between the two.  What is meant by "the current continuous page sequence"?  When I print the two variables in my reports I get the same number for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Total Pages** is used for counting total pages say in a group, before the page break so if group one extends 5 pages it will show you (1-5)  and then start over again for group 2 ex 6 pages so (1-6).

**Overall Total Pages** is for the total pages so lets say if group one has 5 pages and group two has 6 it will show you there are 11 pages so 1-11.